# How to refer to an NSIndexPath?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, tableview, nsindexpath

In my table view, there are 4 sections with 3 rows in the first section, 2 rows in the second section, 2 rows in the third section, and 1 row in the forth section.

How do I refer to these rows when there are pressed? This is the code I'm using so far. Please help

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        println("\(indexPath)")
        switch indexPath {

        case 0.1, 0.2, 0.3:                
           println("Row 1, 2, or 3 in section 1")   

        case 1.1:
           println("Row 1 in section 2")

        case 1.2:             
           println("Row 2 in section 2")    

        case 2.2:
           println("Row 2 in section 3")   

        case 3.1:
           println("Row 1 in section 4")  

        default:
            println("Default")

        }           

 }
```

Comment: you should consider a 2D array for your tableView ( Section and Row)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest using a tuple:

```
switch (indexPath.section, indexPath.row) 
{
  case (0,1), (0,2), (0,3):
    print("Row 1, 2, or 3 in section 1")   
  case (1,1):
    print("Row 1 in section 2")   
  case (4, _):
    print("any row in section 5")   
  default: 
    break
}
```

(Underscore is a "don't care" placeholder that matches any value in that position.)

That way the syntax of each case is nice and easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `indexPath.row` to return its row index and `indexPath.section` to get its section, but both are  `Int`s; be careful.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to `indexPath.section` for sections and `indexPath.row` for rows inside sections

Good luck